# Filtering the results of a SELECT query to avoid certain words in the value of a column?

Tags: mysql-5.5, select, varchar, string, substring

I have a table called ***videos*** with a column named ***title*** and there is a set of words (around 50 words as of now but the number of words may increase) which is the knowledge base for filtering the content.

For example

> porn, pornography, Adult, Boobs, Booty, Tits

pseudo query may be like

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE title NOT LIKE (porn, pornography, Adult, Boobs, Booty, Tits)
```

I checked `NOT LIKE` but I have to do it like

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE title NOT LIKE ‘%porn%’ AND title NOT LIKE ‘%pornography%’ AND title NOT LIKE ‘%Adult%’ AND title NOT LIKE ‘%Booty%’ AND title NOT LIKE ‘%Boobs%’ AND title NOT LIKE ‘%Tits%’
```

which is very inconvenient and inefficient. So is there any other better way to do this ?

Comment: You should have `AND`s there, not `OR`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written this in SQL Server so you may have to translate to MySQL but this should work for you.

```
CREATE TABLE #ExcludeList (ExcludeVal varchar(50))

CREATE TABLE #VideoList (VideoName varchar(500))

INSERT INTO #ExcludeList VALUES ('Prob1'),('Prob2'),('DontUse1')

INSERT INTO #VideoList VALUES ('This is a prob1'),
            ('This is clean'),('This is also clean'),
            ('DontUse1 this one is bad')

SELECT *
FROM #VideoList VL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #ExcludeList EL
                    WHERE VL.VideoName LIKE '%' + EL.ExcludeVal + '%')
```

Comment: Translated to MySQL here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94adef/13/0

Comment: @wBob it worked :)